# SharePoint 2013 Search Result Refiners Showing No Data

Tags: 2013, document-library, search

Inside my document library I have columns named "Departments", "Category", "Sub Category" and "Index". I added data to these columns, re indexed the library and created managed property for them. The property at which was mapped started with ows.... I waited for a full crawl, went to the search page begin to add the created managed property. The results for this show No Entries. I know there are entries but they will not show up. Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked that:

- The documents being crawled are checked in and published (if publishing feature is enabled)?
- That the crawl log in the Search service application shows that SSA actually crawled your documents?
- The user doing the search has at least restricted read access to the documents?

If so, and it still doesn't work, provide more details to your question, and I'll try to guide you further!

Answer (score 2):

To add to Benny's answer also check that you can retrieve the data with a property query before you try refinement. Property:Value should return a result. If it doesn't you need to fix that first. Ensure the property is marked as Retrievable and Refinable.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the managed property you added is set to be used as a refiner, if you edit the managed property you will find a drop down list indicates whether to use the property as a refiner, by default it is set to none, set it to Active